¿Cómo puedo realizar una conexión de Base de Datos si contraté HostGator?
Buen día. Quisiera saber cómo puedo realizar una conexión a mi base de datos que me proporcionó HostGator.
Desde la página de HostGator puedo entrar a mi cPanel y desde cPanel puedo entrar a "phpMyAdmin".
Haré una base de datos para vincularla a mi aplicación en Android, pero primero quiero asegurarme de hacer bien la conexión y por eso voy a testear la conexión desde JAVA.
La cosa es que necesito un usuario, contraseña y una URL para hacer el enlace.
En cPanel creé un usuario nuevo, con contraseña. Le dí todos los permisos para poder operar sin problemas la nueva BD.
En phpMyAdmin cree la BD. Está nueva sin datos agregados por el momento.
Mis dudas por el momento son 2:
1.- En mi aplicación de JAVA para realizar la conexión, debo de poner un usuario, ese usuario ¿es el que cree en cPanel o es el usuario que me aparece en phpMyAdmin? - Porque en la parte derecha de phpMyAdmin aparece una sección que dice "Servidor de Base de Datos" y aparece un nombre de usuario largo que termina con "@localhost". - De igual forma me gustaría saber si la contraseña sería la que creé en cPanel, o la contraseña para hacer la conexión es otra (y en dónde o cómo la puedo encontrar).
2.- Dentro de mi App de Java debo de poner un URL. ¿Qué debo de poner ahí?
Estoy apenas entrando a este tipo de aprendizaje sobre base de datos por lo que no sé si yo esté omitiendo algo obvio o un error común.
Dejaré una imágenes (la primera es sólo la interfaz de cPanel para crear usuarios, y la 2da es de la página principal de phpMyAdmin) y el código de JAVA para hacer la conexión:


Antes de está la sección para declarar los valores de URL, usuario y contraseña. Es un programa pequeño ya que sólo servirá para ver si hay conexión.
'''
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);

        // Hubo éxito
        System.out.println("¡Conectado!");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al conectar a la base de datos: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

'''

Quisiera creer que el usuario y la contraseña fueron los de cPanel, pero aún así necesito saber qué debo poner en el valor de URL de mi programa de JAVA.

Conectarse a una base remota es una mala idea desde mil puntos de vista.. deberias tener un back que se conecte a la db y tu app le pegue a ese back.. si es asi, tu base va a estar en localhost...

Tengo un hosting con Cpanel y solo deja crear usuarios @localhost (supongo que por seguridad), no se si será lo mismo en otros. Si es tu caso, para usarla con tu aplicación Android, o la que sea, no te queda de otra que crear una aplicación backend para que sirva la data. Una forma óptima, segura y que está de moda es con API Rest y tu aplicación móvil o web podría consumirla. Si es un web hosting Linux, deberás implementarla en PHP (a menos que te deje usar otra cosa como Node).

la forma de armar la url tipicamente es 'jdbc:mysql://'+ serverName +':' + port + '/' + database siendo por lo general localhost el servername y 3306 el port.

No te recomiendo conexión directa. Expon los datos vía URL. Para ello debes programar una API o Servicio Web en el servidor y usar Retrofit, Volley u otro en Android para interactuar con la API.

el usuario que ves en el phpmyadmin es el configurado para acceder a la base de datos, es un nombre "largo" porque por lo general los hostings compartidos le agregan al principio el identificador de cuenta o denominacion del servidor ( compartido ) en el cual está la base de datos. el @localhost al final del nombre de usuario indica que sólo se le permite conectar desde el mismo equipo/servidor donde está la base de datos. si tu applicacion java corre en el mismo servidor es todo lo que necesitas. si la app esta en otro lado ahi ya conviene armar algo intermedio.
